# How to inherit or extends TextFieldProps type material ui?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I tried like this

```js
import { Control, FieldError, FieldValues, Path } from "react-hook-form";
import { TextFieldProps } from "@mui/material";

export interface TextFieldControllerProps<InputsType extends FieldValues> extends TextFieldProps {
  control: Control<InputsType>;
  error: FieldError | undefined;
  name: Path<InputsType>;
}
```

The problem is is not reading the type. For example here:

```js
<Controller
  name={props.name}
  control={props.control}
  render={({ field }) => (
    <TextField
      label={props.label}
      variant={props.variant || "outlined"}
      type={props.type || "text"}
      {...field}
      error={!!props.error}
      helperText={props.error?.message}
      InputProps={props.InputProps}
      fullWidth={props.fullWidth}
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      value={props.value}
      onChange={(e) => {
        props.onChange?.(e);
        field.onChange(e);
      }}
      defaultValue={props.defaultValue}
    />
  )}
/>;
```

**All of that should be extended type from TextFieldProps is does not exist**

What the properly way to inherite the type of TextFieldProps